# Autoscaling: Newly created instance always OutOfService

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, autoscaling

I have setup autoscaling using these steps...

> $ elb-create-lb autoscalelb --headers --listener
>   "lb-port=80,instance-port=80,protocol=http" --listener
>   "lb-port=443,instance-port=443,protocol=tcp" --availability-zones
>   us-east-1d
>
> $ elb-describe-lbs autoscalelb
>
> $ elb-register-instances-with-lb autoscalelb --instances i-ee364697
>
> $ elb-configure-healthcheck  autoscalelb --headers --target "TCP:80"
>   --interval 5 --timeout 3 --unhealthy-threshold 2 --healthy-threshold 4
>
> $ as-create-launch-config autoscalelc --image-id ami-baba68d3
>   --instance-type t1.micro
>
> $ as-create-auto-scaling-group autoscleasg --availability-zones
>   us-east-1d --launch-configuration autoscalelc --min-size 1 --max-size
>   5 --desired-capacity 1 --load-balancers autoscalelb
>
> $ as-describe-auto-scaling-groups autoscleasg
>
> $ as-put-scaling-policy MyScaleUpPolicy --auto-scaling-group
>   autoscleasg --adjustment=1 --type ChangeInCapacity --cooldown 300
>
> $ mon-put-metric-alarm MyHighCPUAlarm --comparison-operator
>   GreaterThanThreshold --evaluation-periods 1 --metric-name
>   CPUUtilization --namespace "AWS/EC2" --period 600 --statistic Average
>   --threshold 80 --alarm-actions arn:aws:autoscaling:us-east-1:616259365041:scalingPolicy:46c2d3b3-7f29-42b6-ab64-548f45de334f:autoScalingGroupName/autoscleasg:policyName/MyScaleUpPolicy
>   --dimensions "AutoScalingGroupName=autoscleasg"
>
> $ as-put-scaling-policy MyScaleDownPolicy --auto-scaling-group
>   autoscleasg --adjustment=-1 --type ChangeInCapacity --cooldown 300
>
> $ mon-put-metric-alarm MyLowCPUAlarm --comparison-operator
>   LessThanThreshold --evaluation-periods 1 --metric-name CPUUtilization
>   --namespace "AWS/EC2" --period 600 --statistic Average --threshold 50 --alarm-actions arn:aws:autoscaling:us-east-1:616259365041:scalingPolicy:30ccd42c-06fe-401a-8b8f-a4e49bbb9c7d:autoScalingGroupName/autoscleasg:policyName/MyScaleDownPolicy
>   --dimensions "AutoScalingGroupName=autoscleasg"

After this I'm running this command:

> $ as-describe-auto-scaling-groups autoscleasg --headers

Response:

> AUTO-SCALING-GROUP  GROUP-NAME   LAUNCH-CONFIG  AVAILABILITY-ZONES 
>   LOAD-BALANCERS  MIN-SIZE  MAX-SIZE  DESIRED-CAPACITY
>   AUTO-SCALING-GROUP  autoscleasg  autoscalelc    us-east-1d
>   autoscalelb     1         5         1 INSTANCE  INSTANCE-ID 
>   AVAILABILITY-ZONE  STATE      STATUS   LAUNCH-CONFIG INSTANCE 
>   i-acf48bd5   us-east-1d         InService  Healthy  autoscalelc

And then:

> $ elb-describe-instance-health autoscalelb --headers

It shows:

> INSTANCE_ID  INSTANCE_ID  STATE         DESCRIPTION
>   REASON-CODE INSTANCE_ID  i-ee364697   InService     N/A
>   N/A INSTANCE_ID  i-acf48bd5   OutOfService  Instance has failed at
>   least the UnhealthyThreshold number of health checks consecutively. 
>   Instance

My first problem is:

It automatically creates One extra instance when there is no load on Main instance.

Secondly,
Newly created instance is always OutOfService.

if I change Min Size to 0 using following command:

> $ as-update-auto-scaling-group autoscleasg --launch-configuration
>   autoscalelc --availability-zones us-east-1d --min-size 0 --max-size 5

And trying to put load on instance using xen:

> hg clone http://xenbits.xensource.com/xen-unstable.hg

Autoscaling not creating any instance. Even if I'm running above command on upto 5 session, CPU Utilization reaches to 100% and still no instance is being created.

Please help me...

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you want to achieve but if you want to use autoscaling capabilities to add more instances based on traffic increase or decrease , you need to use the load balancer  parameters (i.e. Latency):

Change yours to: 
--namespace='AWS/ELB'
--metric-name Latency 
--period 60 (this is super quick)
--threshold 2.0 (this is very low)

To test if it works, I use Apache Bench, I run below command on multiple micro instances

```
$ ab -n 10000 -c 10 http://<your ELB>.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/index.php
```